# Как правильно подключить jQuery в Magento?

Tags: php, jquery, magento

Как правильно подключить jQuery аккордеон в CSM Magento?
Имею файл left.phtml который выводит список категорий.
Я так понимаю блок "dl" подключается и оборачивается в скрипт аккордеон?
В данном коде обычный ява скрипт decorateDataList это выражение команды ява скрипт в котором написан сценарий аккордеона вроде как?
И помимо подключения его ещё нужно подключить библиотеку jQuery? А вместо decorateDataList уже писать команды аккордеона?
Много информации перерыл, когда написано сделать на простой html разметке понятно, а вот в моём слечае и внутри CSM Magento не понимаю.:-(

PS Подскажите, хороший аккордеон желательно со значками векторными.

```html
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Каталог') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писал в вопросе аналогичный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478408/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-%D0%B2-cms-magento)

Вот кстати пример очень простого [аккордеона](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)

Comment: Как оказалось, что на magento простой аккордеон не работает, приходится добавлять функцию проверки есть ли вложение во вкладке, если есть, то тогда срабатывает аккордеон. [пример в моём вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605176/how-to-connect-a-cookie) Или вот он же в работе. [аккордеон](https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/no120eqp/10/) Только вот пока куки прикрутить не могу.

Comment: а куда куку то и зачем?

Comment: Чтобы меню оставалось открыто также при переходе на другую страницу. Ещё советуют [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) Я так понял альтернатива для куки, но не понял, что лучше и как такое применить к моему js.

Comment: кстати не нужно подключать для работы с куки ничего в Мадженто, можно использовать её методы, например:

Mage.Cookies.set('name', 'value'); // установить cookie с именем name и значением value
Mage.Cookies.get('name'); // получитьcookie с именем name
Mage.Cookies.clear('name'); // удалить cookie с именем name

вот ссылка тут ещё есть полезное на php и js - http://www.magefast.com/cookie-magento/

Comment: по методам хранеия данных сессия, локал или в куки тут не скажу, нужно смотреть как лучше будет для реализации задачи, вот тут доступно описывают разницу между ними - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies

Comment: Я так понимаю это для php, а тут js. Даже не представляю как переплести такое. Во второй magento обратил внимание, что js подключают для добавления класса, тем самым упрощается аккордеон. В общем для меня это высший пилотаж, с которым пока не смогу разобраться. С аккордеоном то не могу уже которую неделю, чтобы все функции заработали... Вот пример кода из [Magento 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/7yw5wude/1/)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33880/discussion-between-sergey-eremin-and-evgv).