# Как подключить jQuery в CMS Magento?

Tags: jquery, magento

Использую CMS Magento, в шаблоне изначально подключена библиотека `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`. Хочу установить аккордеон для меню. Нужно ли мне помимо этой библиотеки устанавливать jquery-ui accordion? 
Ниже код в файле расширением .phtml с подключённым аккордеоном, но не jquery, a js.

```html
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Каталог') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключение каких-либо скриптов в Мадженто делается очень просто, например:

в собственном модуле, подключаем например в хед

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">          
                   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/filemane.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

или аналогично в page.xml там где подключаются все скрипты и стили

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/filemane.js</name></action>
```

Естественно наш файл должен лежать в текущей теме, напрмер /skin/js/filename.js